# Is it good to link a shared library against other shared libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, shared-libraries

I have an application X which uses shared libraries A,B and C. Shared library C also uses some symbols from Shared library A. Application X is linked against A and B during compile time and it does dlopen to load C at run time.

My question is:

Is it a good idea to link C against A during link time or leave the symbol resolution for runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option 1. But it does not work that way.

1. You link C with A.
   As A is a dynamic lib this will do nothing phsically.
   It verifies that all dependencies will be satisfied by A at runtime.
2. At runtime when you dlopen() the shared lib C
   It will open C and if you had not already linked against A it would also open A
   But since A is already open it will just resolve symbols in C with the A that is open.

Comment: There could be a problem if the application and library C are linked to different major versions of library A. Then both major versions will get loaded and their symbols will mix, unless there's symbol versioning.

Comment: Yes. But that is a separate problem. Let us try and focus on the problem at hand (which in this case is a non issue). If we want to get into versioning then the OP should post a specific question about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the option 2. Leave the resolution for runtime. Late binding is the best option. Also I never knew that option 1 was possible :)